# render specific tag in react js (hook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flutter, react-hooks, render

In flutter when I would like to change state and make changes to specific widget I can use `ValuelistenableBuilder`. But in react js(hook), to change state I can do it with `useState`, but by using useState in a screen (to change one value), all the components in my screen will re-render (All of message "PRINTED", "PRINTED 2", and "NOTIFIER LOG" are printed), I just want the specific tag or component do the re-render, not all of the components. Is that possible to do that. Here is the sample code

```
import React from "react"
import YourComponent from "./Notifier"

const SpecificTag = React.memo(({ value }) => {
  console.log("PRINTED 2")
  return <p>{value}</p>
})

function MyComponent() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState(new Date())

  const handleChange = () => {
    setText(new Date())
  }

  console.log("PRINTED")

  return (
    <div>
      <YourComponent />
      <button onClick={handleChange}>Change State</button>
      <SpecificTag value={text.toLocaleString()} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

and here is `YourComponent`

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  console.log("NOTIFIER LOG")

  return (
    <div>
      <h6>THIS IS TEXT</h6>
    </div>
  )
}

export default YourComponent
```

So whenever I click the button `Change state` I don't want `YourComponent` re-render (I don't want message : `"NOTIFIER LOG"` is printed whenever I click the button)

Comment: Move the `state` and `button` inside `<SpecificTag />` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React.memo to avoid re-render `YourComponent`, the code is below

```js
import React from 'react';

const SpecificTag = React.memo(({ value }) => {
  console.log('render specific tag');
  return <p>{value}</p>;
});

const YourComponent = React.memo(() => {
  console.log('render Your component');
  return (
    <div>
      <h6>THIS IS TEXT</h6>
    </div>
  );
});

function MyComponent() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState(new Date());

  const handleChange = () => {
    setText(new Date());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <YourComponent />
      <button onClick={handleChange}>Change State</button>
      <SpecificTag value={text.toLocaleString()} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

This is the result

[image: interface]

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have tried it and it goes like what I want